# Cannot connect Google Ads to BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-ads-api

I just started using GCP and can't create a data transfer from Ads. I did all steps by [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/adwords-transfer?hl=en_US) but I always get an issue without any explanation.

```
There was a problem saving this transfer config
This transfer config could not be saved. Please try again.
iq
```

sometimes these two letters change, as far as I remember to 'jk'
[image]

Comment: This error might be caused because the user does not have all the necessary permission, can you double check you have the permissions described in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/adwords-transfer?hl=en_US#required_permissions)? For both: BigQuery Data Transfer Service and Google Ads. After that, could you try to set up your transfer through the `bq` command line? Did it work?

Comment: yes, thanks a lot! All permissions were given, but I created a data transfer through bq command line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand, you are not able to create your Data transfer from Google Ads to BigQuery using the console.

This error may be cuase because you do not possess all the necessary permissions, as per [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/adwords-transfer?hl=en_US#required_permissions):

> - BigQuery Data Transfer Service:
>
> bigquery.transfers.update permissions to create the transfer Both
> bigquery.datasets.get and bigquery.datasets.update permissions on the
> target dataset The bigquery.admin predefined IAM role includes
> bigquery.transfers.update, bigquery.datasets.update and
> bigquery.datasets.get permissions. For more information on IAM roles
> in BigQuery Data Transfer Service, see Access control reference.
>
> - Google Ads: Read access to the Google Ads Customer ID or manager
>   account (MCC) that is used in the transfer configuration.

Also, you can set the transfer using the [`bq` command](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/adwords-transfer?hl=en_US#setting_up_a_google_ads_data_transfer),

```
bq mk \
--transfer_config \
--project_id=project_id \
--target_dataset=dataset \
--display_name=name \
--params='parameters' \
--data_source=data_source
```